# Sending Java source to Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-ecf

I use a Java code generator (CA Plex).  Out of the box, it runs an ANT build script to compile the Java.

I wanted to build in Eclipse.

A long time ago I wrote an eclipse plugin that runs a servlet in the Eclipse workbench. I then wrote an ANT task that finds the source I just generated and POST's it to the servlet.  The servlet then writes the posted source to the Java Project.

I want to rework this using as much out of the box standard Eclipse functionality as I can.  I will still have to depend on the ANT task, but that task can be rewritten.  I'd like to be able to have this plug into additional team services available in the Eclipse Workbench

Every time I look at Eclipse ECF for remote services guidance, I get a strong urge to get up, get a snack and take a nap.

Is ECF what I want?

Comment: The created source is included in the Eclipse source folder list, right? I think what you're looking for is the "refresh resources after completion" checkbox in your External Tools Configuration menu (if you start the ANT script using this, that is).

Comment: No, the source does not generate into the workspace.
I don't really want the folder where the source generates in the workspace (linked or otherwise).  I have a bunch of stuff I want to run before it gets sent to an actual Eclipse Java Project source folder.

Comment: You say "the servlet writes the posted source to the Java Project". So you should be able to add it to the Java Build path?

Comment: The Source gets compiled.
The servlet implementation is clunky and inflexible.
I was hoping for something a bit more streamlined.